# Board files for x86 based systems

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, platform

Usually all embedded platform boards such as beaglebone/board, Rasp pi, etc etc have there board files that describe what hardware is present using structure's.

So Is there anything similar for the x86 based systems.
How do we supply platform data for non discoverable devices in x86 systems

Edit: the config allows option to either compile with Device tree support or without it.

> CONFIG_USE_OF=y
>
> CONFIG_DTC=y
>
> CONFIG_OF=y
>
> CONFIG_PROC_DEVICETREE=y

Thanks.
GNA

Comment: FYI: board files are obsolete. [Device Tree](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree) is the modern art to describe boards hardware.

Comment: I know that...but what was the used when device tree was not incorporated in the linux kernel.. Device tree was predominant in SPARC and POWER PC...was it used and is used with x86 also.

Comment: Take a look at this DTS file: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/platform/ce4100/falconfalls.dts?id=refs/tags/v3.18-rc5

Comment: Ok. I saw that file. but the config file gives option to either compile with Device tree support or without it. Then what to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most devices are discoverable through PCI and ACPI.
(Even though most x86 CPUs are not SoCs, they have many built-in PCI devices.)

The few remaining devices (mostly legacy stuff going back to IBM PCs) are hardcoded in the x86 arch code.

Any 'new' devices that aren't PCI must be described by the BIOS in some ACPI table.

Comment: All over `arch/x86/`.